# Get all files from subdirectories modified closest to a particular time

Tags: bash

I have a directory of project submissions from students:

```
+ submissions
|
+-+ Student_Name_1
|
+-+ Student_Name_2
|
+-+ Student_Name_3
|
...
```

Each subdirectory may contain one or more tar/zip/tgz/tar.gz/etc. files.
Some directories may be empty because a student has not submitted at all.

The project submission deadline is at a particular set time. What is the most efficient way (preferably in a BASH script, to keep it simple) to get a copy of only the newest file created before the submission deadline and copy it to another directory with the filename:
 `Student_Name_#--original_file_name.tar/zip`?

Comment: The simplest thing is to shift some of the burden to the students. Accept only a file with a specific name; then the file is either present or not at submission time.

Comment: @chepner I would do that, but I do not have control over the submission script (our department IT group created it) and students are not allowed to submit with the same file name more than once. We want to allow them to submit more than once, so we can't force them to use one file name.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps : If I've understood the requirement to be find the submission closest to the deadline.

```
set -e
touchfile=touchfile
deadline=02010930 #CHANGEME
touch -t $deadline $touchfile
files=`find submissions  -type f  | while read filename ; do
    if [[ $filename -ot $touchfile ]] ; then
        echo $filename
    fi
done`

[[ -n "$files" ]] && {
    thefile=`ls -t $files | head -1`

    [[ -n "$thefile"  ]] && {
        # REMOVE echo when happy :D
        echo cp $thefile $(basename $(dirname $thefile))-$(basename $thefile)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it:

```
DESTINATION="../final"
for D in `find . -type d`
do
    LASTFILE=`cd ${D};ls -art1 *.{zip,tar} | tail -1`
    #note that the last arg of each call is the number one, not the letter 'L'
    cp ${D}/${LASTFILE} ${DESTINATION}/${D}-${LASTFILE}
done
```

Comment: Rather than command-substituting `find . -type d`, I think it's simpler and safer to write `for D in */`. Also, you probably want to do explicitly handle the case that the directory is empty (or at least, empty of `.zip` and `.tar` files). And you should use more double-quotes. :-)